# constructing an expand with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

I am having trouble to create an expand query using the REST API.

I have two lists which are linked.
PIR
Title, Date, Number

SIR
Title, PIR2SIR (lookup to Title in PIR), Date, Number
Now I want to display all listitems from PIR with their related SIR's

```
$.ajax({

    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,Date, Number,Title/PIR2SIR&$expand=Title",
    method: "GET",                                                      
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    timeout: 2000,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
    },
    error: function (xhr,status,error) {
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

My code returns an error. How should I use the linked list in this query?

Comment: What is error your getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand it as

```
$select=Title,Date, Number,PIR2SIR/Title&$expand=PIR2SIR
```

This will give you the value of PIR2SIR field.

Comment: Still get an error with your example. I don't know where it is from. The console just writes error, that's all.

Comment: I changed the code, now the error I get is the field PIR2SIR doesn't exists.

Comment: Your select only works when I use the second list (SIR) as source. But then I get the data in the wrong way.
SIR 1.1  
PIR 1  
SIR 1.2  
PIR 1

Comment: yes, the query will work when you are fetching the data from SIR list since the lookup field is in the SIR list. To display : "all listitems from PIR with their related SIR's" : you can still query the SIR list to get all items which will give you the "PIR2SIR" field (which is the PIR as it is a lookup) and also the corrosponding "title" of SIR. This way you already have a mapping of SIR and PIR...am I missing something ?

Comment: Well I think items in the PIR list which have no SIR are not displayed for one. Secondly I need some code to display them, like:
       for(var i =0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
       {  
     if (eh != data.d.results[i].Eenheid) {
           console.log(data.d.results[i].Eenheid);
            eh = data.d.results[i].Eenheid; }
     if (PIR != data.d.results[i].PIR2SIR.Title) {
        console.log(data.d.results[i].PIR2SIR.Title);
        PIR = data.d.results[i].PIR2SIR.Title; }
        console.log(data.d.results[i].Volgnr);
        console.log(data.d.results[i].Title);

Comment: to get the items from PIR which have no SIR you can fetch the items from SIR list, get the distinct value of the PIR2SIR field. The get the items from the PIR list and find out the items which aren't in the PIR2SIR field value.

Comment: how would that look like in code?